# CSS logo changes its position when text length increases

Tags: html, css

This is my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/tL3vN/1/) which is working fine but when i change my headline2text to "Sale Price $25 . This is a sample text. $244" then auto logo image changes its position. I do not want logo to change its position but it should remain on its place and should not be affected by the headline2Txt. How to fix this issue?

```
 <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="mainContainer">
            <p class="copyrights" id="copyrights"></p>
            <div>
                <img id="Image_Car" src="http://i.share.pho.to/25a090ef_c.png" />
            </div>
                  <div id="headlineText">
            <p id="headline1Txt" >Sample bag1</p>
            <p id="headline2Txt" >Sale Price $25 </p>

        </div>
            <div id="disclaimer" >
               Details*
            </div>
              <div id="Image_logo">
                <img id="Imglogo" src="http://i.share.pho.to/93578bd4_o.png" />
            </div>

           <div >
           <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button"  id="ctaBtn"><div id="fadeIn" >  Learn More Now </div></button>

        </div>
    </div>


#Image_logo img
{
    position:relative;
    width:140px;
    height:30px;
    top:-3px;
left:390px;
}
</div>
```

Comment: Try `position: absolute;` in `#Image_logo img`.

Comment: i tried this absolute/fixed but nothing works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `position: relative;` on **#Image_logo img** yet you try to position it the "absolute way". Try to change your CSS like this:

```
#Image_logo img {
    position:absolute;
    width:140px;
    height:30px;
    top:40px;
    left:390px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I may not understand what you're asking, but I think the lack of a float is throwing you. Adding some css like this..

```
<style>
#Image_logo img {
    width:140px;
    height:30px;
}
#wrapper {
    float:left;
}
</style>
```

...should work. It should be in a separate .css file of course.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving your #Image_logo img position: absolute instead of relative, then modify top, left etc. Then it should be always in the same place;